# What is the output for the following Java program where null is passed as argument for the overloaded methods?

Tags: java, overloading

```
public class Overloading {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Overloading o = new Overloading();
        o.display(null);
    }
    void display(String s) {
        System.out.println("String method called");
    }
    void display(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("Object method called");
    }
}
```

It is giving the output as "String method called". I need the explanation why?

Comment: Run it and see for yourself

Comment: "String method called"

Comment: Yeah..It is giving the output as "String method called". I need the explanation why?

Comment: Null is not an object, as it is in some other languages.

Comment: I answered a similar question earlier. Please see the question I flag this one as duplicate of.

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times before. Please do some searching first.

Comment: @Stieffers `null` is not an `Object`, but it is a [literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7) and has its own `type`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the [Java Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5):

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

First of all: both methods are accessible (obviously) and applicable. They are both applicable, because `null` is of type `nulltype`, which is by definition a subtype of all types. `String` is more specific than `Object`, because `String extends Object`. If you would add the following, you will have a problem, because both `Integer` and `String` are equally "specific":

```
void display(Integer s) {
    System.out.println("Integer method called");
}
```

Comment: I find this explanation incomplete without describing null-type which for the purpose of overload resolution is considered to be subtype of all other types.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Good point, I added it.

Answer (score 4):

Java will always find the most specific version of method that is available.

`String` extends `Object`, and therefore it is more specific.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5